# Is there a reliable source of Deutsche Bahn historical punctuality data?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn, timetables

After missing a few train connections this summer, I'd like to understand if certain train connections aross Europe are reliable.

So I want to build a database of each intercity/long distance train in Europe. For each train, each day, I'd like to know when it ACTUALLY arrived/departed from what stations and when it was scheduled to arrive/depart. Ideally I'd like 1-2 years historical data.

I've used Zugfinder but when I watch and compare that to actual movements in real-time, it doesn't always seem correct. Are there any other sources/feeds?

Comment: This would be a VERY large data base. Germany alone has 25000+ trains/day and I estimate to be 1000 or so to be high speed/long distance (IC,ICE, EC, DB)

Comment: For the UK, https://www.realtimetrains.co.uk is very detailed but only goes back one week in the past. For France, SNCF pretends to be all about open data but information is scarce. Note that from experience, they do have real-time data which is nearly never right as soon as there's a delay, and actual delay information (which they use for compensation requests) which is available once the train has actually arrived or shortly after that, but I don't believe this is published. On the other hand, there's a lot of aggregate punctuality data https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/?q=train+retards

Comment: You may want to browse [the European Data Portal's transport category](https://data.europa.eu/data/datasets?categories=tran), but finding the data you're looking for in there is a full-time job!

Comment: I suppose you've checked DB's open data page? https://data.deutschebahn.com/dataset.groups.apis.html I don't see anything relevant, but my German is rusty

Comment: @jcaron The new site is https://developers.DeutscheBahn.com/ and _no_, all _interesting_ data is not freely available. About a half year ago I wanted to get some (machine-readable) timetable information (future _and_ past), but you can only retrieve information concerning _current_ trains. It’s really designed just for travelers _on the journey_ using their mobile devices, the application using some of these open APIs.